# Amazon S3 and Yii2

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, yii2

I created a code to use Amazon S3 using this composer component:

https://github.com/2amigos/yii2-resource-manager-component

This worked very well.

But I changed my server and when I upload a image to Amazon S3 I received this error:

```
PHP Fatal Error – yii\base\ErrorException
```

Class 'Aws\S3\Enum\CannedAcl' not found

I did not change anything of code, I dont understand why this error, I cant find a solution
How can I fix it?

This is the complete error :

```
PHP Fatal Error – yii\base\ErrorException

Class 'Aws\S3\Enum\CannedAcl' not found
1. in /opt/app-root/src/admapps/vendor/2amigos/yii2-resource-manager-component/AmazonS3ResourceManager.php at line 78
69707172737475767778798081828384858687 * @return \Guzzle\Service\Resource\Model
*/
public function save($file, $name, $options = [])
{
$options = ArrayHelper::merge([
'Bucket' => $this->bucket,
'Key' => $name,
'SourceFile' => $file->tempName,
'ACL' => CannedAcl::PUBLIC_READ // default to ACL public read
], $options);

$this->getClient()->putObject($options);
}

/**
* Removes a file
* @param string $name the name of the file to remove
* @return boolean
*/
2. in /opt/app-root/src/admapps/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/base/InlineAction.php at line 55 – app\controllers\BeersController::actionUploadlogobeer()
3. in /opt/app-root/src/admapps/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/base/InlineAction.php at line 55 – call_user_func_array:{/opt/app-root/src/admapps/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/base/InlineAction.php:55}()
4. in /opt/app-root/src/admapps/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/base/Controller.php at line 154 – yii\base\InlineAction::runWithParams()
5. in /opt/app-root/src/admapps/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/base/Module.php at line 454 – yii\base\Controller::runAction()
6. in /opt/app-root/src/admapps/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/web/Application.php at line 87 – yii\base\Module::runAction()
7. in /opt/app-root/src/admapps/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/base/Application.php at line 375 – yii\web\Application::handleRequest()
8. in /opt/app-root/src/admapps/web/index.php at line 13 – yii\base\Application::run()
78910111213require(__DIR__ . '/../vendor/autoload.php');
require(__DIR__ . '/../vendor/yiisoft/yii2/Yii.php');
require(__DIR__ . '/../helpers/Utils.php');

$config = require(__DIR__ . '/../config/web.php');

(new yii\web\Application($config))->run();
```

Comment: This extension uses "aws/aws-sdk-php": "2.5.2" and it's very old (at GitHub version 3.18 is latest). AWS said they've removed CannedAcl in version 3 so it should not make impact on 2.5.2 (it is present in 2.5.2). Anyway there is the same issue reported about this https://github.com/2amigos/yii2-resource-manager-component/issues/10

Comment: Thanks, You are right. I need to update my code.

Answer (score 0):

Posted by Bizley

This extension uses "aws/aws-sdk-php": "2.5.2" and it's very old (at GitHub version 3.18 is latest). AWS said they've removed CannedAcl in version 3 so it should not make impact on 2.5.2 (it is present in 2.5.2). Anyway there is the same issue reported about this github.com/2amigos/yii2-resource-manager-component/issues/10 – Bizley